# Intel DPDK Compilation Error

Tags: makefile, intel, dpdk

I'm having problem in compiling the Intel DPDK on my Fedora and I really need that.

This is what I have in my terminal:

```
[gois@localhost dpdk-1.5.2r1]$ make install T=i686-default-linuxapp-gcc
================== Installing i686-default-linuxapp-gcc
== Build scripts
== Build scripts/testhost
== Build lib
== Build lib/librte_eal
== Build lib/librte_eal/common
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio
make: *** /lib/modules/3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64/build: File or directory not found.  Stop.
make[7]: ** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
make[6]: ** [igb_uio] Error 2
make[5]: ** [linuxapp] Error 2
make[4]: ** [librte_eal] Error 2
make[3]: ** [lib] Error 2
make[2]: ** [all] Error 2
make[1]: ** [i686-default-linuxapp-gcc_install] Error 2
make: ** [install] Error 2
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please paste English output...

Comment: Oh, sorry, english output is "File or directory not found. Stop." and "Erro" means "Error"... Thank you @LaszloPapp!

Comment: yes, I google translated it, but still, it is better to update the original post so that the readers do not need to go through the comments to understand such things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install linux headers:

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

Then build/ should be a symlink to files needed to build kernel modules.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Thomas, the problem seems to be with the build folder, not the missing headers themselves at first glance. Why do you think it would fix the issue?

Comment: it can be put as a comment instead of question. it is mentioned in the previous comment @LaszloPapp

Comment: @Saurabh: comment instead of question? I do not follow. Also, why would you put use comment if you think a solution is right? Just tell Thomas if there are issues. This long "It is wrong, but I do not point out why" is not necessary.

Comment: @LaszloPapp my previous comment was mistyped. I mean to say "Comment instead of Answer". i felt the answer was not a solution to the question asked in terms of length and content as it lacked much explanation. if you feel that the answer is appropriate then i appreciate it. i will delete my first comment if so.

Comment: @Saurabh: I personally do not think Thomas' answer fixes the issue, but at least I let him know why, so he can address my concern if I am wrong. Just saying "this is not an answer" does not let Thomas know why it may or may not be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RTE_KERNELDIR variable is not set correctly. The installer is not able to access kernel level parameters.