# Build DPDK 17.11.5 fail using dpdk-setup.sh in OS RedHat 3.10.0-862.rt56.804.el7.x86_64

Tags: build, redhat, dpdk

I was trying to build DPDK environment using dpdk-setup.sh but can't get DPDK to compile.

```
$sudo ./dpdk-stable-17.11.5/usertools/dpdk-setup.sh
```

I type 14(x86_64-native-lunuxapp-gcc) to build DPDK show the errors below:

**error message image**

[image]

Could someone help me to fix this?

I have found these post but still don't understand to fix this problem..

[dpdk-compilation-error-when-building-igb-uio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271227/dpdk-compilation-error-when-building-igb-uio)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `kernel-devel` package installed. It may also be a good idea to update the kernel, since RHEL7 has kernel version 3.10.0-1062 available now.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK by default look in `lib/modules/{kernel}` folder for Kernel headers and definitions. So fix for your build issue is get the right headers and using Redhat, Centos or Fedora make sure to wither `export RTE_KERNELDIR=your desired path` in terminal or build with `RTE_KERNELDIR=<your desired path> make`.